# How to save an HTML form as draft and then retrieve and fill the rest on later time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-history

I have an html form that takes and stores information in MySql database using php. Lets call this form's file name as "form.php".

This form is called whenever we want to enter information of an object. Let's call one of the object's name as 'x'.In order to fill information for it, the url goes like [www.domain.com/form.php?object=x](http://www.domain.com/form.php?object=x) and we fill details for x.

Similar goes for another objects like 'y' and 'z'
viz.   [www.domain.com/form.php?object=y](http://www.domain.com/form.php?object=y) and [www.domain.com/form.php?object=z](http://www.domain.com/form.php?object=z).

Now my question is how can I partially fill forms for these objects and then complete and submit them at later stage of time. Many solutions target form just for one url, I have same form with multiple url variables.

Comment: This is no different than a full / complete form submission.  You may want to add a flag to indicate whether the form is partial or complete.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to allow the user to submit the form in parts, ie page 1 (submit) page 2 (submit) page 3 (submit) page 4: "Review" - and this is the final submit and this is when the form gets processed.

And using JavaScript ajax, you can do the same sort of thing with just one long page by sending the partial form answers to the backend and then showing them if/when the form is reloaded